# Get directions between two points and to draw them on a map

Tags: angular

i'am using @agm/core in angular 4, and I want to get Directions between two points to draw them on the map, but i don´t know how to do it.
There is little documentation on the official website, the version of the @agm/core i got is 1.0.0-beta.1

HTML code:

```
<agm-map>
  <agm-polyline>
    <agm-polyline-point *ngFor="let coordinate of coordinates" 
      [latitude]="coordinate.latitude"
      [longitude]="coordinate.longitude">
    </agm-polyline-point>
  </agm-polyline>
</agm-map>
```

Component code:

```
public coordinates: [
 {
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number,
 }
];
```

Answer (score 3):

Code HTML template:

```
  <agm-map
      [latitude]="lat"
      [longitude]="lng"
      >


      <agm-marker
        *ngFor="let coordinate of coordinates; let i=index"
        [latitude]="coordinate.lat"
        [longitude]="coordinate.lng"
      ></agm-marker>
      <agm-polyline
       [visible]="true"
       [strokeWeight]="3">
        <agm-polyline-point
          *ngFor="let coordinate of coordinates; let i=index"
          [latitude]="coordinate.lat"
          [longitude]="coordinate.lng">

        </agm-polyline-point>
      </agm-polyline>

     </agm-map>
```